# How do you know if the output of a if statement is true or false?

Tags: c++

I'm a beginner in C-programming. Here is one of my programs:

```
int friends = -2;
int beatles = 100;
int baseball = 1;

if  (friends + beatles >= baseball )
```

How do you find out if the statement is true or false? 
Any help is appriectiated!
Thanks!

Comment: hope you didn't do this
`if  (friends + beatles >= baseball ) cout<<"false"; else cout<<"true";`

Comment: @coderredoc, i know, at least put some whitespaces in there.  Sheesh!

Comment: @TriHard8.: Where..? In a comment I think.... :-(

Comment: @lurker this is not how it will get decomposed the `>=` will be evaluated before the `+` check again.

Comment: @AhmedAkhtar nope. See the [C operator precedence chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence). `+` has higher precedence than `>=`. And if you compile this code and examine the assembly output, you'll see that the `+` occurs first, followed by the comparison.

Comment: @lurker Ohh... right thanks very much.

Comment: I haven't learned how to use if (friends + beatles >= baseball ) cout<<"false"; else cout<<"true"; yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if  (friends + beatles >= baseball )

```
friends = -2
beatles = 100;
```

so it will evaluate to (-2)+(100) = 98

which is greater than baseball (1)

so you condition is always true;

Comment: Tha's really helpful! Thanks for the help.